# Query SQL Searching inside value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've a database that's looking simular like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| PKey   |   name    |   date   |  Snippet                                |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1    |   Harry   |2016-05-03|<menu><emp1>1</emp1><emp2>2</emp2></menu>|  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   2    |   Barry   |2016-05-03|<menu><emp1>7</emp1><emp2>0</emp2></menu>| 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   3    |   Tarry   |2016-05-01|<menu><emp1>3</emp1><emp2>6</emp2></menu>| 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I'm tryin to do is searching inside the "Snippet" like :

```
SELECT Pkey, Snippet.value('(/Snippet/emp2)[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
FROM *name* (NOLOCK) 
WHERE date >= '2016-05-02'
AND date <= '2016-05-04'
AND Snippet.value('(/Snippet/emp2)[1]', 'varchar(max)') >= '1'
```

What I expect is PKey  1 because he is between the dates and emp 2 is bigger than 1 unlike PKey 2.
Still I din't get any result.
Does anyone knows what I'm doing (or thinking) wrong?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is value() a standard function in mysql ? which version ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)

Comment: Will it always be this structure?

Comment: @sagi yes it will be , but the snippet may be not... sometime the <emp1></emp1> maybe missing.
Iff thats what you mean

Answer (score 1):

The XQuery Path doesn't look correct as the root node in your xml is menu not snippet. Can you try updating the path to

```
 Snippet.value('(/menu/emp2)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```